# Do I need to free constant memory assigned using cudaMemcpyToSymbol?

Tags: cuda

I am pretty sure the answer is no, but I just wanted to make sure as I don't want memory leaks.

I am using the following code

```
__constant__ void* VERTEX_NO_CONSTANT_PARAMETER;
HANDLE_ERROR( cudaMemcpyToSymbol( VERTEX_NO_CONSTANT_PARAMETER, &vertexNo, sizeof( int ) ) );
HANDLE_ERROR( cudaFree( VERTEX_NO_CONSTANT_PARAMETER ) );
```

It does not throw any errors at me which is putting doubt in my mind (I was hoping that cudaFree would error).

Thank you!

Kevin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you don't. According to NVIDIA cuda library:

> cudaFree (void *devPtr)  Frees the memory space pointed to by devPtr,
>   which must have been returned by a previous call to cudaMalloc() or
>   cudaMallocPitch() [...]

Answer (score 3):

In the question you declare the constant void* VERTEX_NO_CONSTANT_PARAMETER. The declaration reserves sizeof(void*) in the constant memory. This 4/8 bytes is allocated by the CUDA driver when the CUDA module is loaded and freed when the CUDA modules is unloaded.

If you call cudaMalloc in your host code and copy the device pointer to VERTEX_NO_CONSTANT_PARAMETER using cudaMemcpyToSymbol then you are still responsible for freeing the device memory using cudaFree after the program is done using the device memory. If you do not free the memory the driver will free the memory when the CUDA context is destroyed.

CUDA does not provide an API to dynamically allocate constant memory. Constant memory can only be statically allocated using `__constant__` qualifier.